# Assembly - Binary Bomb Confusion

Tags: assembly, x86, binary

I have an assignment for reverse engineering a binary. The function I'm up to takes a string input and reads one character at a time. It is as follows (push/pop registers removed):

```
 8048b6e: mov    $0x8049ee9,%esi 
 8048b73: movzbl (%esi),%edx ; (%esi) = 0x654A6167
 8048b76: test   %dl,%dl
 8048b78: je     8048bb2 
 8048b7a: mov    0x8(%ebp),%ebx
 8048b7d: mov    $0x16,%edi
 8048b82: movzbl (%ebx),%eax
 8048b85: sub    $0x61,%eax
 8048b88: cmp    $0x19,%al
 8048b8a: ja     8048b97 
 8048b8c: mov    %edi,%ecx
 8048b8e: sub    %al,%cl
 8048b90: mov    %ecx,%eax
 8048b92: jns    8048b97 
 8048b94: add    $0x1a,%eax
 8048b97: add    $0x61,%eax
 8048b9a: cmp    %al,%dl
 8048b9c: je     8048ba3 
 8048b9e: call   8048e18 
 8048ba3: add    $0x1,%esi
 8048ba6: movzbl (%esi),%edx
 8048ba9: test   %dl,%dl
 8048bab: je     8048bb2 
 8048bad: add    $0x1,%ebx
 8048bb0: jmp    8048b82
```

I'm having a little trouble understanding the logic of one part (8048b85 onwards) so I converted it to C

```
eax = *ebx;                                 // movzbl (%ebx),%eax
eax -= 97;                                  // sub    $0x61,%eax
```

```
// cmp    $0x19,%al
// ja     8048b97 <phase_3+0x32>
if((unsigned)(eax & 0xFF) < 25)
{
  ecx = edi;                                // mov    %edi,%ecx
  int cl = (eax & 0xFF) - (ecx & 0xFF);     // sub    %al,%cl
  ecx &= cl;
  eax = ecx;                                // mov    %ecx,%eax

  if(cl >= -127 && cl < 128)                // jns    8048b97
  {
    eax += 0x1A;                              // add    $0x1a,%eax
  }
}
eax += 97;                                  // add    $0x61,%eax
if((eax & 0xFF) != (edx & 0xFF))            // cmp    %al,%dl
{
  trigger_bomb();                           //  call   8048e18 <trigger_bomb>
}
```

I'm not sure if what I converted to is correct. The first value being compared is 0x67 which is g in ascii which wont set the flag for ja as 0x19 > 0x67 - 0x61. If I try 0x67 - 0x1A as the input, since it's unsigned comparison it will never be < 25 as it will overflow back to 236. I thought then I would need to use a negative number so that if it overflows, it would go 0x67 but since the input is ascii I'm not sure that it is possible to input a negative value.

So my question is where am I going wrong in my logic? I'm not looking to be given the answer since I will need to figure out the other 3 values, but what I'm trying just doesn't seem to be correct. Any pointers/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thankyou

Answer (score 2):

The problem was sadly my own stupidity.. First issue,

```
int cl = (eax & 0xFF) - (ecx & 0xFF);
```

Has the arguments around the wrong way (dest = dest - source not dest = source - dest)

And second was my confusion about the JNS instruction. I misinterpreted it as signed byte not the sign flag thus,

```
if(cl >= -127 && cl < 128)
```

should have been written as

```
if(cl < 0)
```

After a week of trying to work this out the answer was rather annoying :)

Answer (score 1):

The `0x61` is a well-known value in the ASCII table it corresponds to the `a` character. And, in fact, when you encounter:

```
8048b85: sub    $0x61,%eax
```

It usually means that you are shifting a character from the usual printable characters intervals down to the unprintable characters values.

I didn't take a deep look at your code, but I really suspect that what is done here is about encoding an ASCII text into a set of unprintable characters.

But, it is just a wild guess (taken in less than 5 minutes). So, beat me if I am wrong ! :-)